# Can I ask "What is the name of X"?

Tags: discussion, questions

Can I ask a question of this type:

> I forgot the name of this software. What was the name of software that
>   does A,B,C?

If not, does SE have an appropriate site for this?
Thanks.

Reference to my *on hold* question: https://superuser.com/questions/993781/what-is-the-name-of-the-coding-site-where-you-could-contribute-your-own-tutorial

Comment: You didn't ask about software.  You asked about a website.  **I am not saying it is on topic**, but a "what website was this", [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would better then Superuser.  Honestly as written your question is way to vague.  There are trillions of websites, a good chuck, would fit that description.  Be sure you read the rules at [WebApps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) before you ask your onhold question there.

Comment: Website is software in my humble opinion... But if we are really nitpicky about it I asked about a "service" - which just happens to be a website. *sigh* I feel like SU is really hostile at times. I mean I know how to ask questions on SO because I am a programmer, but here - every time I ask, I feel like I did something wrong. Instead of directing me somewhere (like this is better suited for X), my question just gets closed. Am I reading this all wrong?

Comment: We don't consider a website to be software.  We consider a website to be a web application.  Please check out the help center.  **How have we been hostile exactly?**  All that has been done currently, is your question was put into a holding pattern, until it can be edited either by you or the community to be within the scope of Superuser.

Comment: You were told the reason somebody was voting to close, before the question was closed, you simply didn't agree.  You have 9 questions, nearly 200 reputation points, I would assume you know what is and isn't on topic.  So I would not specifically call out the correct place if I was the one to casted a close vote I expect you to know it.  Looking at your past closed questions, you have been told since 2012, that software recommendations are not on topic.  You really should check out the help center.

Comment: It isn't me who would be nickpicking anyways.  The help center is very specific about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a guessing game question.

Consider these options instead

- "How do I do A,B,C on OS Y?"
  can be asked on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) (so focus on the process)

or

- "I need a software that does A,B,C on OS Y" with details on the specific requirements can be asked on the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: So much for webapps and software recs :( : http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26111/what-is-the-name-of-the-coding-site-where-you-could-contribute-your-own-tutorial http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86107/what-is-the-name-of-the-coding-site-where-you-could-contribute-your-own-tutorial